# Analysis on fields other than the Complex and Real numbers?

Tags: analysis

There is complex analysis and there is real analysis. Is there any other analysis defined on any other field, i.e. 'can we perform calculus on fields other than the real and complex numbers'?

Comment: You might start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_analysis

Answer (score 1):

Sure: some folks do analysis on p-adic fields, and some do analysis on [the quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_analysis). (Yes, that is a noncommutative field.)